# Python Behave - ConfigError: No steps directory in []

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-behave

Following the tutorial for setting up behave (https://behave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html), I'm getting a `ConfigError: No steps directory` in error message.

My file structure:

```
VS Code/TestingAutomationPOC/
VS Code/TestingAutomationPOC/features/
VS Code/TestingAutomationPOC/features/steps/
VS Code/TestingAutomationPOC/features/steps/tutorial.py
VS Code/TestingAutomationPOC/feature/tutorial.feature
```

Installed behave (1.2.6) via pip.

Added `"python.linting.pylintArgs": ["--load-plugin","pylint_protobuf"]` to user settings which fixed my import issue but did not help with this ConfigError.

From `tutorial.py`:

```
from behave import *

@given('we have behave installed')
def step_impl(context):
    pass

@when('we implement a test')
def step_impl(context):
    assert True is not False

@then('behave will test it for us!')
def step_impl(context):
    assert context.failed is False
```

From `tutorial.feature`:

```
Feature: showing off behave

  Scenario: run a simple test
     Given we have behave installed
      When we implement a test
      Then behave will test it for us!
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Will it work if you change into your `TestingAutomationPOC` directory and run `behave` from there? I suspect you are running the behave command from a directory other than the one that has your `features` file, and behave doesn't know where to look.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the command:

`behave **/feature_file_name`

Comment: you could also do `behave **/` to run all the features

Comment: you may run a single feature file by specifying file path(absolute to relative) `behave python-bdd/features/Sample_REST_API_Testing.feature` or `behave ~/pythonp/python-bdd/features/Sample_REST_API_Testing.feature`

Answer (score 1):

Basically in this case your ".feature" file is inside "feature" folder where as steps folder is inside "features" folder. Both of them should be on same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your working directory in VisualStudio is probably not correct.

HINTS:

- Print the command-line how behave is executed
- Print the current working directory for this execution (cmd-shell: `%CD%`)
- Provide your own python script "my_behave.py" to run behave. It can easily shown/print the diagnostics above.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue. First thing you need to make sure your folder path is correct. Second thing , create `steps` folder inside your project `features` folder. now run the `behave` command with feature file name or without file name, it should work.

```
├── feature [folder]
│   |── steps [folder]
├── filename.feature [file]
```